# Getting ActiveRecord to Query from What it Already Has Cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

I frequently run into this situation.

```
post_comments = post.comments
#grabs maybe 3 records out of thousands in the table
do_something_with post_comments

#...later in the same request...

subset_of_comments = post_comments.where(:awesome=>true)
#hits the database again :-(
do_something_else subset_of_comments
```

I realize that the database is very good at finding records, but I don't see how going back to the full table and looking through thousands of records is better than searching the small set of records attached to this post that's already cached for the 1 or two I need.

What could I do if I wanted to improve the efficiency of this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the select method:

```
subset_of_comments = post_comments.where(:awesome=>true)
# becomes
subset_of_comments = post_comments.select{ |pc| pc.awesome == true }
```

[Documentation Array (Ruby 1.9.3),`#select` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-select)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. After you loaded AR:Relation first time, all records have been cached. But if you pass another request `.where()` or other, it pull query again. If you want to search within cached records, do not send `.where`, and just operate with **array methods**.

```
# second 'request':
subset_of_comments = post_comments.map {|comment| comment if comment.awesome == true}.compact
```

Array methods:
`.find` - for one first matched record. `.map` or `.collect` - for collection

Your comment object must have 'awesome' public reader.

Comment: Incorrect! This would not return a subset of post_comments. Just an array of boolean values.

Comment: you're right, ive just changed find to map and forget to correct the block

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty blindingly obvious, actually. For some reason I had a mental block about using the ruby enumerable functions. I guess I just thought it would be cool if ActiveRecord remembered if I had previously done that filter somewhere else.